# Find the matrix representation of a quadratic form Q(x,y).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Let $v=(x,y)^T$ a vector of $R^2$ and the quadratic form $Q(x,y)=4x^2+2xy+4y^2$.Find the matrix representation $A$ of $Q(x,y)$.

What I know is that you can represent the quadratic form $Q(x,y)=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2$ as   $Q(x,y) = x^TAx=\left[\begin{array}{cc} x & y  \end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b \newline b & c \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc} x \newline y\end{array}\right]$

Is $ A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \newline b & c \end{bmatrix}$ the representation matrix?
And if not ,what is the matrix?

Comment: since they don't divide by $2,$   the matrix is half the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives.

Comment: Yes @Trimidis ${}$